# Random variable outcome

Tags: javascript, spotify

At school we are busy making a Spotify application. I am currently making an application where I get images from LastFM, from the current artist now playing. I get three random images shown.I am now trying to make sure that the 3 random images can't be the same.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var randno       = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );
var randno2      = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );
var randno3      = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );
```

Now I want to make sure that they are not the same. Can anybody help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [while loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp):

```
var randno = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );    

var randno2 = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );
while (randno2==randno)
{
   randno2 = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );
}

var randno3 = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );
while (randno3==randno || randno3==randno2)
{
   randno3 = Math.floor ( Math.random() * artistImages.length );
}
```

Comment: This could theoretically compute forever. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of indexes, shuffle them with the Fisher Yates shuffle and then slice off `3`.

```
function fisherYates ( myArray ) {
  var i = myArray.length;
  if ( i == 0 ) return false;
  while ( --i ) {
     var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     var tempi = myArray[i];
     var tempj = myArray[j];
     myArray[i] = tempj;
     myArray[j] = tempi;
   }
}

var arr = new Array(artistImages.length + 1).map(function(val, index) { 
                                                    return index; 
                                                 });

var rands = fisherYates(arr).slice(0, 3);
```

Fisher Yates implementation from [here](http://sedition.com/perl/javascript-fy.html).

Comment: I do get what you are doing here, but I go for the first answer as it is easier for me to understand. Thanks for your answer though!